# How do I pass dynamic parameters as arguments

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have the following code :

```
from tkinter import *


class GUI: 
        
    def __init__(self,master):
        
        
        self.ip_word  = Label(master,text="Input Path")
        self.ip_word.grid(row=0,sticky=E)   
        
        self.ip_path_field = Entry(master)
        self.ip_path_field.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=W)
        
        self.op_word  = Label(master,text="Output Path")
        self.op_word.grid(row=2,sticky=E)
        
        self.op_path_field = Entry(master)
        self.op_path_field.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky=W)
        
        self.filename_word=Label(master,text="Output Filename ")
        self.filename_word.grid(row=4,sticky=E)
        
        self.filename =Entry(master)
        self.filename.grid(row=4,column=1,sticky=W)
        
        self.Submit = Button(master,text="Submit",fg="black",bg="white",command=self.Scraper(ip_path_field,op_path_field,filename) )
        self.Submit.grid(row=5,columnspan=2)
    """        
    def printMessage(self):
        str1=ip_path_field
        str2=op_path_field
        str3=filename
        Scraper(str1,str2,str3)"""
     
    
    
    def Scraper(self,ip_path_field,op_path_field,filename):
        import pandas as pd
        import os
        # "C:/Users/chowdhuryr/Desktop/first automation/MAIN RESEARCH DATA.xlsx"
        user_input =ip_path_field#input("Enter the input file path of your file: ")
        
        if os.path.exists(user_input):
               df = pd.read_excel(user_input, sheetname='Sheet1')
               print("File Found and We are Processing !")
        else:  
            print ("Input Directory does not exists.")
        #"C:/Users/chowdhuryr/Desktop/first automation/OUTPUT DATA.xlsx"
        user_output =op_path_field#input("Enter the output file path of your file: ")
        
        #if os.path.exists(user_input):
               #df = pd.read_excel(user_input, sheetname='Sheet1')
        #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        #setting up the path 
        import os
        os.chdir('C:/Users/chowdhuryr/Desktop/first automation')
        
        df=df[0:5]
        #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        #importing necessary packages 
        from selenium import webdriver 
        #from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
        from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
        
        #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        
        
        #Setting up Chrome webdriver 
        #chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--headless") #making the window work in the background
        options.add_argument('window-size=1200x850')
        
        
        #declaring a list to store the messages 
        Message=list()
        
        Tier=list()
        
        Wirecentre=list()
        
        
        
        #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        #iteration to access the url and and retriving the Tier Locations 
        
        for i in range(0,df.shape[0]): #(0,df.shape[0]):
            
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/chowdhuryr/Desktop/first automation/chromedriver', chrome_options=options) #openning chrome
            #driver.maximize_window() #maximizing the window 
            
            driver.get('https://clec.att.com/facilitiescheck/facilities_chk.cfm') #openning the url 
            
            street_address=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input') #accessing the street address field 
            street_address.send_keys(df['CIRCUIT_LOC_ADDR'][i].split(',')[0])  #passing the values to street_address location 
            
            city=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input') #accessing the city to street address field 
            city.send_keys(df['CIRCUIT_LOC_ADDR'][i].split(',')[1]) #passing the values to the city location 
        
            state=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/select') #accessing the state field 
            state.send_keys(df['CIRCUIT_LOC_ADDR'][i].split(',')[2]) #passing the values to the state field 
        
            checkbox=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[1]/input') #accessing the checkbox 
            checkbox.click()  #clicking on the check box 
        
            search_button=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[1]/input') #accessing the submit button 
            search_button.submit() #clicking the submit button 
           
            #try-except block in case if radio button appears 
            try:
                Address=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/b') #taking the xpath of the address block 
                if (Address):         #checking if it contains any radio button or not 
                    Radio_button=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/input') #getting the xpath of radio button 
                    Radio_button.click()   #clicking the radio button                                                                           
                    submit_button=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table[3]/tbody/tr[2]/td/input') #getting the submit button
                    submit_button.submit()
            except NoSuchElementException:
                 print('no such element found')
                 
                
                
                
            message_body= driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="msg"]/table/tbody/tr/td').text #Extracting the Message from the message box 
            Message.append(message_body[14:]) #putting the message into a text 
            
            str = message_body.split() #splitting the message 
            
            if any ("Tier"in s for s in str):
               j=str.index('Tier')
               Tier.append(str[j+1])
            else:
               Tier.append("NULL")
               
            if any ("AT&T"in s for s in str):
               j=str.index('AT&T')
               Wirecentre.append(str[j+1])
            else:
               Wirecentre.append("NULL")
           
            #saving the screenshot 
            str=df['STRIP_EC_CIRCUIT_ID'][i]
            filename="C:\\Users\\chowdhuryr\\Desktop\\first automation\\"+str+".png"  #Taking the circuit id name 
            driver.get_screenshot_as_file(filename)
        
            driver.close() #closiing the driver 
            
        #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        
        #putting the back thenew columns into the dataframe and storing it into an excel sheet 
            
        df['Tier']=Tier   #putting the Tier column back into the dataset 
        df['Wirecentre']=Wirecentre #putting the Wirecentre column back into the dataset 
        df['Message']=Message  #putting the Message column back into the dataset 
        if os.path.exists(user_output):
            user_output="user_output"+filename+".xlsx"
            writer = pd.ExcelWriter(user_output)    #writing the dataframe down into a new excel file 
            df.to_excel(writer,'sheet1',index=False)        #to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')    
            writer.save()
        else:
            print ("Output Directory does not exists.")
            
        
        #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        
        #Generating pop up window at the end of the process 
        popup_driver=webdriver.Chrome()
        popup_driver.maximize_window()
        popup_driver.execute_script(" window.alert('Process is Completed');") #generating the pop up """
        




root =Tk()
b=GUI(root) 
#b.Scraper(ip_path_field,op_path_field,filename)   
root.mainloop()
```

Now what I want to do is this :

I want to pass the variables ip_path_field,op_path_field,filename as arguments to the function named **scraper** . Now ip_path_field,op_path_field,filename are all user inputs and not hard coded strings. Now whenever I run the following code, I get the GUI opened and whenever I provide my inputs in the required edit boxes and press the submit button I get the following error name 'ip_path_field' is not defined. My purpose of this code is to pass the user defined file paths to the function called **scraper**() as defined in the code above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Button parameter “command” executed when declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767228/why-is-button-parameter-command-executed-when-declared)

Comment: No I tried the option where I passed in the command an intermediate function without any parameter from which I called my Scrapper function. But that also shows the same error.

Comment: And in addition to the question I linked, you try to pass `ip_path_field`, which is the Entry object itself. To get the content of the Entry widget use `ip_path_field.get()`.

Comment: File "C:/Users/chowdhuryr/Desktop/first automation/Audit_file.py", line 38, in printMessage
    str1=ip_path_field.get()

NameError: name 'ip_path_field' is not defined  This is the error I get.

Comment: @fhdrsdg I have tried to pass a parameter less function from the command in Button() in __init__ which in turn calls my Scrapper(). But this shows the same old error.

Comment: Oh yeah it's `self.ip_path_field`, not `ip_path_field`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a callback that gets the values, and then passes them to the function that does the work.

Example:

```
class GUI: 

    def __init__(self,master):
        ...
        self.Submit = Button(..., command=self.handle_submit)
        ...

    def handle_submit(self):
        ip_path = self.ip_path_field.get()
        op_path = self.op_path_field.get()
        filename = self.filename.get()

        self.Scrapper(ip_path_field,op_path_field,filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem you are having is related to how you built your method. Instead you should have put the `get()` calls inside that method. This way you can simple run the command to call scraper without needing to pass arguments. I have taken your code and re-written it to more closely follow the PEP8 standard with the method correction included.

You only need to apply the `self.` prefix to class attributes/methods. Things like labels/buttons that are not going to be modified later in the code should be left as normal widgets that are not assigned as attributes.

Next I moved all your imports to the top of the code. You only need to import a library one time and it should all be listed at the top of your code. On imports keep in mind it is better to `import tkinter as tk` instead of using `*` to prevent any accidental overrides occurring.

I have changed your string concatenation to use the `format()` method as `+` is deprecated.

Here is your code with some basic clean up as well.

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
import os
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

class GUI: 
    def __init__(self,master):
        tk.Label(master, text="Input Path").grid(row=0, sticky="e")
        tk.Label(master, text="Output Path").grid(row=2, sticky="e")
        tk.Label(master, text="Output Filename").grid(row=4, sticky="e")

        self.ip_path_field = tk.Entry(master)
        self.op_path_field = tk.Entry(master)
        self.filename = tk.Entry(master)

        self.ip_path_field.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="w")
        self.op_path_field.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="w")
        self.filename.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky="w")

        tk.Button(master, text="Submit", fg="black", bg="white",
               command=self.scrapper).grid(row=5,columnspan=2)

    def scrapper(self): # changed function to a method.
        user_input = self.ip_path_field.get(0, "end")
        user_output = self.op_path_field.get(0, "end")
        filename = self.filename.get(0, "end")

        if os.path.exists(user_input):
            df = pd.read_excel(user_input, sheetname='Sheet1')
            print("File Found and We are Processing !")
        else:  
            print ("Input Directory does not exists.")

        os.chdir('C:/Users/chowdhuryr/Desktop/first automation')
        df = df[0:5]

        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--headless")
        options.add_argument('window-size=1200x850')

        message = list()
        tier = list()
        wirecentre = list()

        for i in range(0,df.shape[0]):

            driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/chowdhuryr/Desktop/first automation/chromedriver', chrome_options=options)
            driver.get('https://clec.att.com/facilitiescheck/facilities_chk.cfm') 
            street_address = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input') 
            street_address.send_keys(df['CIRCUIT_LOC_ADDR'][i].split(',')[0]) 
            city=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input') 
            city.send_keys(df['CIRCUIT_LOC_ADDR'][i].split(',')[1]) 
            state = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/select') 
            state.send_keys(df['CIRCUIT_LOC_ADDR'][i].split(',')[2]) 
            checkbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[1]/input') 
            checkbox.click() 
            search_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[1]/input') 
            search_button.submit()

            try:
                address = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/b') 
                if (address):
                    radio_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/input') 
                    radio_button.click()
                    submit_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table[3]/tbody/tr[2]/td/input')
                    submit_button.submit()
            except NoSuchElementException:
                print('no such element found')

            message_body = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="msg"]/table/tbody/tr/td').text 
            message.append(message_body[14:]) 
            strx = message_body.split() 

            if any ("Tier"in s for s in strx):
                j = strx.index('Tier')
                tier.append(strx[j+1])
            else:
                tier.append("NULL")

            if any ("AT&T"in s for s in strx):
                j = strx.index('AT&T')
                wirecentre.append(strx[j+1])
            else:
                wirecentre.append("NULL")

            strx = df['STRIP_EC_CIRCUIT_ID'][i]
            filename = "C:\\Users\\chowdhuryr\\Desktop\\first automation\\{}.png".format(strx)
            driver.get_screenshot_as_file(filename)
            driver.close() 

        df['Tier'] = tier
        df['Wirecentre'] = wirecentre
        df['Message'] = message
        if os.path.exists(user_output):
            user_output="user_output{}.xlsx".format(filename)
            writer = pd.ExcelWriter(user_output)
            df.to_excel(writer, 'sheet1', index=False) 
            writer.save()
        else:
            print ("Output Directory does not exists.")

        popup_driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        popup_driver.maximize_window()
        popup_driver.execute_script(" window.alert('Process is Completed');")

root = tk.Tk()
b = GUI(root) 
root.mainloop()
```

All that said you should try to use a minimal code next time. It is easier to fix issues when you narrow it down to exactly the problem. For example based on your question a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would look something like this.

```
from tkinter import *
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

class GUI: 
    def __init__(self,master):

        self.ip_path_field = Entry(master)
        self.ip_path_field.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=W)

        self.op_path_field = Entry(master)
        self.op_path_field.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky=W)

        self.filename =Entry(master)
        self.filename.grid(row=4,column=1,sticky=W)

        self.Submit = Button(master, text="Submit",
                         command=self.Scrapper(ip_path_field,op_path_field,filename) )
        self.Submit.grid(row=5,columnspan=2)

    def Scrapper(self,ip_path_field,op_path_field,filename):
        user_input = ip_path_field
        user_output = op_path_field
        filename = filename


root = Tk()
b = GUI(root) 
root.mainloop()
```